# Class Instance variables in C extended python

Tags: python

I have a python module to perform matrix operations and want to code it in C as a C python module using the Python/C api. I am using a class called `Matrix`, and I want to continue to use the class model. I can initialize the class, but cannot figure out how to use instance variables like I would in python `self.var`. I have tried looking at documentation and tried looking for examples, but I cannot find anything to help.

**matrix.c**

```
struct matrixStruct {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    float **matrix;
};

static PyObject * Matrix_init(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {

    int cols, rows;
    PyObject *selfv;
    struct matrixStruct m;
    Py_INCREF(Py_None);

    // __init__ takes two args, rows, cols
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,"Oii",&selfv,&rows,&cols)){
        perror("ParseTuples");
        return NULL;
    }
    m.rows = rows;
    m.cols = cols;

    // Create the matrix
    m.matrix = malloc(m.rows*sizeof(float *));
    if (m.matrix == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m.rows; i++) {
        m.matrix[i] = malloc(m.cols*sizeof(float));
        if (m.matrix[i] == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    //init the matrix with all 0
    for (int i = 0; i < m.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.cols; j++) {
            m.matrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    return Py_None;
}

static PyMethodDef ModuleMethods[] = { {0, 0} };

PyMODINIT_FUNC initMatrix(void) {

    PyMethodDef *def;

    PyObject *module = Py_InitModule("Matrix", ModuleMethods);
    PyObject *moduleDict = PyModule_GetDict(module);
    PyObject *classDict = PyDict_New(  );
    PyObject *className = PyString_FromString("Matrix");
    PyObject *matrixClass = PyClass_New(NULL, classDict, className);
    PyDict_SetItemString(moduleDict, "Matrix", matrixClass);
    Py_DECREF(classDict);
    Py_DECREF(className);
    Py_DECREF(matrixClass);

    for (def = MatrixMethods; def->ml_name != NULL; def++) {
        PyObject *func = PyCFunction_New(def, NULL);
        PyObject *method = PyMethod_New(func, NULL, matrixClass);
        PyDict_SetItemString(classDict, def->ml_name, method);
        Py_DECREF(func);
        Py_DECREF(method);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you read the [C-API tutorial on creating new types](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes.html)?

Comment: @user2357112 I have not yet, but just from looking over it, it looks as if it has what I need! Thank you for pointing that out, I will get back to you on this!